# Reference Typescript project outside of the source folder

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I have 2 CRA projects in a mono-repo - P1 and P2.

```
root/
  projects/
    p1/
      package.json
      tsconfig.json
      src/
        shared/
          **/*.ts
    p2/
      package.json
      tsconfig.json
      src/
        **/*.ts
```

`P1` contains some shared infrastructure source files, which I want to reuse in `P2`.

*Note:* I know about the disadvantages and negative sides of this approach, but...

What I tried:

1. Include `P1` from `P2` and import:

   - `P1 tsconfig.json` modified with

     `"include": [..., "root/projects/p1/src/shared/**/*.ts]`
   - `P2` source file imports .ts files by relative path

   Result:

   ```
   You attempted to import <path> which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
   You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/
   ```
2. Use yarn workspaces

   This one is easy. Yarn [does not allow](https://legacy.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/) to have workspaces outside of the project root

   `You cannot and must not reference a workspace that is located outside of this filesystem hierarchy.`
3. Typescript 3.0+ projects references:

   - Update `p1 tsconfig.json` with

   `"compilerOptions": { "composite": true }`

   - Add reference to `P1 tsconfig.json`

   `references: [ { "path": "{...}/p1/" ]`

   - Build `P1` with `tsc -b` to produce declaration files
   - now I need to import it somehow.

     - create `tsconfig.paths.json` to [configure](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5645#issuecomment-437481406) `paths` section
     - add `rootDir` tp `P1 tsconfig.json` to point to `root/` folder
     - add paths `"@lib/*": ["<relative-path-to-p1>/p1/src/shared/*"]`

   Result:

   `Cannot find module: '@lib/....'. Make sure this package is installed`

   Also I see that VSCode recognizes my configuration properly and `import` intellisense works properly
4. Use `react-app-rewired`

   in my `config-overrides.js` I added something like

   ```
   module.exports = function override(config, env) {
     config.resolve.alias = {
       "@lib": path.resolve(__dirname, '...p1/src/shared/')
     }
   }
   ```

   This works for all aliases inside the project. But in my case it fails with

   ```
   You attempted to import <root>/p1/src/shared... which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
   You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Add `customize-cra` and `react-app-rewired` packages
2. Add to referenced `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true
}
```

3. Create `tsconfig.paths.json` in the base project

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@alias/*": ["..relative/to/base/url/path/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

4. In `tsconfig.json` add such lines:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "<the same value as in paths file>"
  },
  "references": [
    { "path": "../relative/path/to/referenced/project/tsconfig.json/file" }
  ]
```

5. Create `config-override.js` file in the project root

```
const { override, removeModuleScopePlugin, getBabelLoader, addWebpackAlias } = require("customize-cra");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require('fs');

const updateAliases = (config) => {
  const aliases = {
    "@alias": ["absolute/path/to/base/url"]
  };

  return addWebpackAlias(aliases)(config);
};

const updateIncludes = (config) => {
  const loader = getBabelLoader(config, false);
  const commonPath = path.normalize(path.join(process.cwd(), "../relative/path/to/referenced/project/tsconfig.json/file")).replace(/\\/g, "\\");
  loader.include = [loader.include, commonPath];
  return config;
};

module.exports = override(
  updateAliases,
  updateIncludes,
  removeModuleScopePlugin()
);
```

6. Use `react-app-rewired` instead of `react-scripts` in `package.json`

*Note*: This is the modified code, so some minor changes may be required.

Comment: It could be really helpful if instead `../all/of/those/random/paths` you could use the correct paths of a given structure.

Comment: please show me your case, so maybe I'll be able to help with it. it is literally a relative path to the referenced project. actually it builds an absolute path in this code from relative. you can change it as you wish

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't know if this is the "right" way or not, but I've done this before by using file watcher (watchman, gulp, etc.) to sync files from Project B into a shared folder in Project A.

When using this approach, make sure to .gitignore the copied files.

Project A
|_ package.json
|_ src
..|_ index.ts
..|_ shared
.....|_ someSharedFile.ts

Project B
|_ gulpfile.js
|_ src
...|_ someSharedFile.ts

https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/

--

Another alternative would be to create an NPM package from Project B and install it to Project A.

Comment: thank you for this option. I'm trying to keep a single copy of files (including mirroring of files)

Comment: "You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/"

So I never tried adding a symlink, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: I thought about this approach as well. this is my emergency plan. I thought it would be possible to solve this reference with a more straightforward approach e.g. project reference, workspace, etc.